# Select SUM from multiple tables for every record in MySQL table

Tags: mysql

I'm having a table with main invoice data, and two table with invoice items:

- items which are based on hourly work, with an hourly rate and an amount of hours
- items which are products, with a unit count an unit price

For the invoice overview page, I'd like to retrieve all invoices and their total amounts with one query.

**A simplified schema**

invoices_main

```
|  invoice_id  |  
|  1           |
|  2           |
|  3           |
```

invoices_items_products

```
|  item_id |  invoice_id | item_count  | item_unit_price |
|  1       |  1          | 1           | 999.95          |
|  2       |  1          | 20          | 49.50           |
|  3       |  2          | 3           | 15.00           |
|  4       |  2          | 5           | 5.00            |
|  5       |  3          | 2           | 150.00          |
```

invoices_items_hourly

```
| item_id | invoice_id | item_hours | item_hourly_rate |
| 1       | 1          | 3.50       | 90.00            |
| 2       | 1          | 1.00       | 140.00           |
| 3       | 2          | 12.00      | 90.00            |
| 4       | 3          | 1.50       | 90.00            |
```

With the help of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11241952/mysql-combine-select-with-sum-from-other-table) question, I've constructed the following query:

```
SELECT 
    I.invoice_id, 
    IFNULL(
        SUM(ROUND(P.item_unit_price * P.item_count, 2)), 
        0
    ) + IFNULL(
        SUM(ROUND(H.item_hourly_rate * H.item_hours, 2)), 
        0
    ) AS invoice_total_amount
FROM 
    invoices_main I 
LEFT JOIN invoices_items_products P ON I.invoice_id = P.invoice_id 
LEFT JOIN invoices_items_hours H ON I.invoice_id = H.invoice_id 
GROUP BY 
    I.invoice_id
```

It works kind of, but if an invoice has both products and hourly items, with at least multiple entries for one of both, items are duplicated due to the joins and the total amount becomes way too high.

Thus, in the above example schema, it goes wrong with invoice_id 1 and 2, but work with 3.

How can I retrieve a list of invoices with their respective total amounts, in a way that works even if an invoice has multiple products and multiple hourly items?

Comment: Do the SUM as a subquery.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I did solve it that way in the end, something similar to Qlii256's answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try putting both left join's into a subquery instead.

```
SELECT
    I.invoice_id,
    IFNULL
    (
        (
            SELECT SUM(ROUND(H.item_hourly_rate * H.item_hours, 2))
            FROM invoices_items_hours AS H
            WHERE H.invoice_id = I.invoice_id
        )
        , 0
    ) +
    IFNULL
    (
        (
            SELECT SUM(ROUND(P.item_unit_price * P.item_count, 2))
            FROM invoices_items_products AS P
            WHERE P.invoice_id = I.invoice_id
        )
        , 0
    ) AS invoice_total_amount
FROM invoices_main AS I
GROUP BY I.invoice_id
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, you should sum up the revenue in each table per `invoice_id` before doing the join. If you're looking to get the revenue from both of these places then you can add `(B.unit_revenue + C.hourly_revenue) total_revenue` to the first `SELECT` statement below.

```
SELECT A.invoice_id, B.unit_revenue, C.hourly_revenue FROM
invoices_main AS A
JOIN (
    SELECT invoice_id, SUM(item_count * item_unit_price) unit_revenue 
    FROM invoices_items_products GROUP BY invoice_id
) B
ON 
    A.invoice_id = B.invoice_id
JOIN (
    SELECT invoice_id, SUM(item_hours * item_hourly_rate) hourly_revenue FROM
    invoices_items_hours GROUP BY invoice_id
) C
ON
    A.invoice_id = C.invoice_id
```